# How to access file path for XML file in an assembly folder?

Tags: c#, .net

In my .NET assembly I need to access an XML file which is in 'Import' folder off my class assembly project.

How do I do this? Almost like ASP.NET `Server.MapPath()` but for an assembly. I don't want the reflection method of getting the currently executing assembly as this points to the GAC folder. I want the folder of the current project.

I also need this to work when being deployed. Basically it is importing an XML file and inserting the seed data using EF Code First database initializer.  This is bootstrapped in the Global.asax.cs.  I need it to work both in development and on live target.

Comment: There is no such thing as the folder of the current project for an assembly. So, what do you really want?

Comment: @Daniel, ok so if I have an XML in my project and I need to read the XML file where does the XML file go and how do I access it?

Comment: Have you imported your file into assembly as embedded resource? If yes, say so; otherwise you can't access it.

Comment: @abatishchev - I like the sound of embedding the XML file in the assembly, but for a one-off population of the database is this the best option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Visual Studio -> item (e.g. XML file) -> Properties -> Build Action -> Embedded Resource
2. `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(path)`

Answer (score -1):

Add the path and/or filename to an app/web.config file and use the functionality in the core System.Configuration assembly to retrieve the value.

Answer (score -1):

How about using:  [`Environment.CurrentDirectory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.currentdirectory.aspx)
Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1343406/environment-currentdirectory-is-yielding-unexpected-results-when-running-installe/1343464#1343464) for more info.

*Update:*
For asp.net, you can use [`Request.PhysicalApplicationPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.physicalapplicationpath.aspx)

Comment: the problem is I'm using EF code-first within my data service assembly and so has no access to the HttpContext at that level.

Answer (score -1):

you could use

```
HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpruntime.appdomainapppath.aspx