# How to get the current directory path of application's shortcut

Tags: c#, console-application

I want to get the current directory path but not of the application location but of it's shortcut location.

I tried these but they return the application's location.

```
Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase);
Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
Path.GetDirectoryName(Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[0]);
```

Comment: By `shortcut location`, you mean the actual *.lnk file that points to the actual *.exe?

Comment: I don't know if its extension .ink but yes its a file that points to the actual .exe

Comment: On windows machines, the extension is *.lnk

Comment: @psubsee2003 i didn't know i went to shortcut properties but it didn't show me extension :D

Comment: You seem to assume that there will be one and exactly one shortcut to the application. This isn't *generally* true.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I didn't assume that... I want the shortcut to put on my 20 folder or whatever other folders to get some information

Comment: When you refer to "**the** shortcut" or "**it's** shortcut", you *are* implying that there is only one.

Comment: Yes at this example.. I assumed if it work for one it will work for more too

Comment: @Loclip If you want it `to get some information` (presumably configuration and/or settings stored in the same location as the shortcut), how can you guarantee that the user will launch the application from the shortcut you want?

Comment: @psubsee2003 because I will tell to the users to do that. Actually this program get the folder name of shortcut location, search on google and get the first page of google search and write it to an html file on the same folder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If adding a COM Object reference is not a problem , Add COM Object Reference - Windows Script Host Object Model

i ran this code in my desktop folder and it did work. for current folder use -   `Environment.CurrentDirectory`

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using IWshRuntimeLibrary;  //COM object -Windows Script Host Object Model

namespace csCon
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Folder is set to Desktop 
            string dir = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
            var di = new DirectoryInfo(dir);
            FileInfo[] fis = di.GetFiles();
            if (fis.Length > 0)
            {
                foreach (FileInfo fi in fis)
                {
                    if (fi.FullName.EndsWith("lnk"))
                    {
                        IWshShell shell = new WshShell();
                        var lnk = shell.CreateShortcut(fi.FullName) as IWshShortcut;
                        if (lnk != null)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Link name: {0}", lnk.FullName);
                            Console.WriteLine("link target: {0}", lnk.TargetPath);
                            Console.WriteLine("link working: {0}", lnk.WorkingDirectory);
                            Console.WriteLine("description: {0}", lnk.Description);
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Code Reference from Forum : http://www.neowin.net/forum/topic/658928-c%23-resolve-lnk-files/

Comment: This answer finds a shortcut from the Windows Desktop, but does not find the shortcut that actually started the program.

Answer (score 6):

According to the process API reference in MSDN, the process `STARTUPINFO` struct for a given process contains the information about the shortcut .lnk file in the title member. There is a flag present in the `dwFlags` struct member that is set when this is the case - so it appears that this is not always set (im guessing if you ran the exe directly)

From MSDN:

> STARTF_TITLEISLINKNAME: 0x00000800
>
> The lpTitle member contains the path of the shortcut file (.lnk) that the user invoked 
>     to start this process. This is typically set by the shell when a .lnk file pointing to 
>     the launched application is invoked. Most applications will not need to set this value.
>     This flag cannot be used with STARTF_TITLEISAPPID.

[Reference here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686331%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Environment.CurrentDirectory
```

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/system.environment.currentdirectory.aspx):

> Gets or sets the fully qualified path of the current working directory.

Comment: Won't this return the application path and not the shortcut path?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1343406/environment-currentdirectory-is-yielding-unexpected-results-when-running-install This link explains it further from the opposite perspective of trying to get the Assembly Directory

Comment: Depending on the point in OP's code where he uses this, current directory may not be the shortcut directory location. He would have to call this as soon as his program begins execution and hopefully no other program changes it as `Environment.CurrentDirectory` is an Environmental variable open to change by all applications

Answer (score 1):

I think you will need to use COM and add a reference to "Microsoft Shell Control And Automation", as described in [this](http://www.saunalahti.fi/janij/blog/2006-12.html#d6d9c7ee-82f9-4781-8594-152efecddae2) blog post:

Here's an example using the code provided there:

```
namespace Shortcut
{
    using System;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.IO;
    using Shell32;

    class Program
    {
        public static string GetShortcutTargetFile(string shortcutFilename)
        {
            string pathOnly = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(shortcutFilename);
            string filenameOnly = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(shortcutFilename);

            Shell shell = new Shell();
            Folder folder = shell.NameSpace(pathOnly);
            FolderItem folderItem = folder.ParseName(filenameOnly);
            if (folderItem != null)
            {
                Shell32.ShellLinkObject link = (Shell32.ShellLinkObject)folderItem.GetLink;
                return link.Path;
            }

            return string.Empty;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const string path = @"C:\link to foobar.lnk";
            Console.WriteLine(GetShortcutTargetFile(path));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you didn't understand my question... Lets say I have one exe and made a shortcut of it in one folder... When i run shortuct i want it to show the location of shortcut

Answer (score 0):

using System.Reflection;

```
 string currentAssemblyDirectoryName = Path.GetDirectoryName(
                                        Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
                                                .Location
                                        );
```

Also for webapplications you can use:

Web Applications:

```
Request.PhysicalApplicationPath
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.physicalapplicationpath.aspx

to grap the applicationpath :)

Comment: This will get the assembly's directory's path rather than the path of the directory that contains the shortcut which launched the application.

Answer (score 0):

Since creating the shortcut is part of the workflow, just set the working directory to "%cd%" for the shortcut then, in the app, use:

```
Environment.CurrentDirectory
```

Obviously, you would want to capture this value before any code your app calls can change it.

When creating a shortcut using Windows Explorer, you don't have the option of setting the working directory. So, after creating it, open its property page by right-clicking on it and selecting Properties, then set the **Start in** field to `%cd%`. After creating such a shortcut, you can move or copy it to the folders in which you want the app to run.

Answer (score 0):

## If you do not want to use a COM object as suggested in the other answers

You can open the file as a regular text file, split on the `\x00` 0 char, and inspect the resulting string array. One of them will be obviously the link target: something like `"C:\path\to\file"` or in case of UNC `"\\computers\path\to\file"`.

```cs
string lnkFilePath  "...";

var file = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(lnkFilePath);
var contents = Regex.Split(file, "[\x00]+");
var paths = contents.Where(line => Regex.IsMatch(line, @"^([A-Z]:\\|^\\\\)\S+.*?"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `GetStartupInfoW`, it will tell you the .lnk file that was launched to start the program.