# Getting path from a ExecutableFile.exe shortcuts

Tags: c#, windows, forms, path, shortcut

I have an (.exe) shortcut in a unknown folder (i.e. c:\dev) , pointing to my application.

I've been trying to obtain the shortcut path anytime my application is started by the **shortcut**.

I've tried different ways such as like Application.StartupPath , but it returns the path to the application executable file, and not the path to the shortcut.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the current directory path of application's shortcut](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15758941/how-to-get-the-current-directory-path-of-applications-shortcut)

Comment: There isn't any way to find the .lnk file back from your process.

Answer (score 1):

This code will help you. :)

```
namespace Shortcut
{
    using System;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.IO;
    using Shell32;

    class Program
    {
        public static string GetShortcutTargetFile(string shortcutFilename)
        {
            string pathOnly = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(shortcutFilename);
            string filenameOnly = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(shortcutFilename);

            // This requires a COM Reference to Shell32 (Microsoft Shell Controls And Automation).
            Shell shell = new Shell();
            Folder folder = shell.NameSpace(pathOnly);
            FolderItem folderItem = folder.ParseName(filenameOnly);
            if (folderItem != null && folderItem.IsLink)
            {
                Shell32.ShellLinkObject link = (Shell32.ShellLinkObject)folderItem.GetLink;
                return link.Path;
            }

            return string.Empty;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const string path = @"C:\link to foobar.lnk";
            Console.WriteLine(GetShortcutTargetFile(path));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the problem, is that i don't know the link path. It can be located in c:\ o c:\dev or whatever I need, so I can't use (const string path = @"C:\link to foobar.lnk";). I'll have different link in the system pointing to a only one .exe, so I need the path from the link who called the .exe

Comment: This helped me fine the target for a .lnk file received via drag-and-drop. Some tips: You have to add a COM reference to Shell32, and its type library is named "Microsoft Shell Controls And Automation". Make sure "Embed Interop Types" is True on that reference. Also, if you don't know whether your input is a shortcut or not, then you should change the conditional in the code above to use IsLink like: if (folderItem != null && folderItem.IsLink).

Answer (score 0):

If you need to change the flow of your program from different shortcuts then pass an argument from each shortcut and read it in the main(args).

If you just need to get the shortcut folder then ensure that 'start in' text is blank and get the folder using

```
Environment.CurrentDirectory
```

Comment: I was using this rigth now, but the problem is that if a client moves the .lnk into o folder the path from the argument will be invalid. I'm searching something like passing the current path of the link as an argument i.e (directory=%currentDir%)*, but doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution if you don't want to mess around with adding obsolete DLL's to your assembly:

```
private static string LnkToFile(string fileLink) {
    List<string> saveout = new List<string>();

    // KLUDGE Until M$ gets their $^%# together...
    string[] vbs_script = {
        "set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject(\"WScript.Shell\")\n",
        "set Lnk = WshShell.CreateShortcut(WScript.Arguments.Unnamed(0))\n",
        "wscript.Echo Lnk.TargetPath\n"
    };

    string tempPath = System.IO.Path.GetTempPath();
    string tempFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(tempPath, "pathenator.vbs");

    File.WriteAllLines(tempFile, vbs_script);


    var scriptProc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    scriptProc.StartInfo.FileName               = @"cscript"; 
    scriptProc.StartInfo.Arguments              = " //nologo \"" 
                + tempFile + "\" \"" + fileLink + "\"";
    scriptProc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow         = true;
    scriptProc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute        = false;
    scriptProc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    scriptProc.Start();
    scriptProc.WaitForExit();

    string lineall 
       = scriptProc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd().Trim('\r', '\n', ' ', '\t');

    scriptProc.Close();

    return lineall;
}
```