# Could not find a part of the path of a file when window service reads it

Tags: c#, .net, directory, windows-services, filesystems

I am writing a window service in c#, my service reads a file(initialisation.ini) and i give the path of this file using the code below and it gives error on reading this file(the path problem) and i tried to run the same code in console application for testing and it works fine with console application but gives error below **only** when i try to install window service, I print the error in file which is as follows on service install:

```
the error reading file is : System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Files\initialisation.ini'.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.StreamReader..ctor(String path, Encoding encoding, Boolean detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.StreamReader..ctor(String path, Encoding encoding, Boolean detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks, Int32 bufferSize)
   at System.IO.StreamReader..ctor(String path, Encoding encoding)
   at System.IO.File.InternalReadAllLines(String path, Encoding encoding)
   at ReadingFileFromFolder.Service1.readFile() in c:\Users\ACER\Desktop\KT-iNDIA\November\5thNovemberKtIndia2015\ReadingFileFromFolder\ReadingFileFromFolder\Service1.cs:line 60
```

The actual path on debugging on working console application is :

```
C:\Users\ACER\Desktop\KT-iNDIA\November\5thNovemberKtIndia2015\ReadingFileFromFolder\ReadingFileFromFolder\Files\initialisation.ini
```

I don't know why it show path as `C:\Files\initialisation.ini` in text file (in this error).

My code corresponding to the error is :

```
            try
            {
                string appRootDir = new DirectoryInfo(Environment.CurrentDirectory).Parent.Parent.FullName;
                var filePathAndName = Path.Combine(appRootDir, "\\Files\\initialisation.ini");
                lines = File.ReadAllLines(filePathAndName);
                foreach (string line in lines)
                {
                    folderInvestigationBureau(line);                   
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                m_streamWriter.WriteLine("the error reading file is : " + e);
            }
```

**EDIT :** Even after changing to  `string appRootDir = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;` I tried to print the appRootDir to get the path of running executable service , it don't print any path. **Is there any account related problem,This is my project installer properties http://prntscr.com/8z7s15 and this is entry in registry http://prntscr.com/8z8ivu , Also note that i need to give password when i login to my computer to open my account. If thats the problem**

**How to solve this ?**

Answer (score 0):

You need to use: AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory

```
string appRootDir=AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
```

In case if this is not the right path, do comment the location which you are getting now

Comment: it still gives same error, please see the edit to know which line gives this error. Please note that the given code works in console application but not in Window service and the reason is this https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/827421 , But how to solve it ?

Comment: your approotDir is the location where your service exe is kept? and what is the location which you got from AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory

Comment: No its not the path of service, it is the path of text file which my service reads.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1343406/environment-currentdirectory-is-yielding-unexpected-results-when-running-install here is one reference link.. why one should not rely on Environment.CurrentDirectory. what is the location which you got from AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory

Comment: And solution :)  to my question ?

Comment: what is the location which you got from AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory -- 3rd time asking ..lol

Comment: it's written in error : Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Files\initialisation.ini'. but actual location is : C:\Users\ACER\Desktop\KT-iNDIA\November\5thNovemberKtIndia2015\ReadingFileFromFolder\ReadingFileFromFolder\Files\initialisation.ini

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94279/discussion-between-amit-dayama-and-struggling).